# Time Based Streaming

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to figure out how to get time-based streaming but on an infinite stream. The reason is pretty simple: Web Service call latency results per unit time.

But, that would mean I would have to terminate the stream (as I currently understand it) and that's not what I want.

In words: If 10 WS calls came in during a 1 minute interval, I want a list/stream of their latency results (in order) passed to stream processing. But obviously, I hope to get more WS calls at which time I would want to invoke the processors again.

I could totally be misunderstanding this. I had thought of using `Collectors.groupBy(x -> someTimeGrouping)` (so all calls are grouped by whatever measurement interval I chose. But then no code will be aware of this until I call a closing function as which point the monitoring process is done.

Just trying to learn java 8 through application to previous code

Comment: I think you want the RxJava library.

Comment: Yeah, we recently ported our stuff to this. It works. Previously we had been using Esper which has a sql-like syntax.

Answer (score 2):

By definition and construction a stream can only be consumed once, so if you send your results to an inifinite streams, you will not be able to access them more than once. Based on your description, it looks like it would make more sense to store the latency results in a collection, say an ArrayList, and when you need to analyse the data use the stream functionality to group them.

Comment: Yeah, I was starting to come to this conclusion. It syntactically so similar to RxJava that I thought for sure I could make it work. But it seems I would have to do all the data grouping and management. Not what I want.